# PHP - Replace Warning with error (using soap)

Tags: php, soap

I am using SOAP to get data from some server (data coming in .xml) . But sometimes SOAP server is down and I need to display some error message instead of :

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 2: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /var/www/class/data2.php on line 619 Warning: simplexml_load_string(): in /var/www/class/data2.php on line 619 Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in /var/www/class/data2.php
```

My code is:

```
$client = new SOAPClient ( 'link.wsdl' ); // initiate new SoapClient
$password ['_'] = 'PASSWORD'; // password for authenticate_user function in SoapHeader
$encoded = new SoapVar ( $password, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT ); // make SoapVariable out of $password
$header = new SoapHeader ( 'http://soapinterop.org/echoheader/', 'authenticate_user', $encoded ); // put authenticate_user method, and password in header
$client->__setSoapHeaders ( $header ); // set SoapHeader
$response = $client->get_details ($this->vin); // calling get_details with the vin given in the form field
$xml = simplexml_load_string ( $response ); // converting the response string to xml
$json = json_encode ( $xml ); // converting to an array in to easy steps (step 1)
$array = json_decode ( $json, TRUE ); // step 2
```

What I want: 
Replace Warning message with something like: "This service is temporary unavaliable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string ( $response );
```

check if

```
$xml === false
```

and set the error message accordingly

http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php

Comment: Thank you :) This was ai Looking for. I try to write something simillar but i failed :(

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in manual the `simplexml_load_string` function:

**Returns an object of class SimpleXMLElement with properties containing the data held within the xml document, or FALSE on failure.**

So simply check if it fails and if it does echo your **This service is temporary unavaliable**

To get rid of this warning consider to `ini_set('display_errors', '0');` on production